# Is it possible to inline Meteor server methods definitions?

Tags: meteor

For simple client to server Meteor method calls, I sometimes find the extra abstraction to be an annoyance. Is it possible to define server methods inline? For example, I would like to replace this:

```
// server.js
Server.methods({ foo: console.log('bar') })
// client.js
Meteor.call('foo')
```

With this:

```
client.js
Meteor.call(() => console.log('bar'))
```

According to the documentation this is not possible, because `call` expects a name.

Comment: how are you going to run JS on the server if it's only served to the client? (i.e. client.js)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot define method only on client. As methods are defined on server.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-methods

> Calling methods on the server defines functions that can be called remotely by clients.

Defining method on client (when defined on server) is used for method (UI) simulation.

> Calling methods on the client defines stub functions associated with server methods of the same name...

There is a great package developed by Meteor development group for working with methods:
https://github.com/meteor/validated-method